# Google Maps Api Marker Cluster Activate?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm using Google Maps to set some markers. I have things setup so that when an item in a list is hovered on the marker will highlight.

This is done easy enough by keep a hash of the markers. So that when I hover over an item it just updates the icon in the marker.

```
this.markers[hoverItem.id].setIcon('/img/map/active-marker.png');
```

This works just fine. However I'm also using the `marker-clusterer-plus` plugin with Google Maps. The problem I'm having is to highlight the cluster icon if the marker is inside.

I can't find away to access the cluster object of the marker. Is there anyway to access or set it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/blob/master/src/markerclusterer.js)...:

...you'd probably need to call [MarkerClusterer.getClusters](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/blob/master/src/markerclusterer.js#L1172) to get all the clusters.

Then loop through them, perhaps then calling [Cluster.getMarkers](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/blob/master/src/markerclusterer.js#L391) and checking if your marker is in each cluster's array of markers.

`Cluster.isMarkerInClusterBounds` and `Cluster.isMarkerAlreadyAdded_` might also be useful.